# How to solve this Planning Domain Definition Language (PDDL) question?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

These are 5 action descriptions with conditional effects:

> Action(A, Precond:{X}, Effect:{when P : ~X), Z})
>
> Action(B, Precond:{Y}, Effect:{when Z : ~P), ~Y,~Z,X})
>
> Action(C, Precond:{~Z}, Effect:{when P : ~X), Y})
>
> Action(D, Precond:{~X}, Effect:{when Q : X)})
>
> Action(E, Precond:{Z}, Effect:{when Q : ~Z)})

**What state would result from executing the action sequence [E,D,A,B,C] in the state {P,Q,Y,Z}?**

I know the answer but I really don't know how to achieve it. Anyone please shed some light? (Please include workings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will turn my comment into an answer.  Recall that if your state is $\{P,Q,Y,Z\}$, and an effect of an action is $\sim\!Z$ (from now on written $\neg Z$), then the new state will *not* contain $Z$, i.e., the state will be, if nothing else is an effect, $\{P,Q,Y\}$.

Since the question asks what the result of a sequence of actions will be, we need to solve this in the order of that sequence.  The sequence asked was 
$[E,D,A,B,C]$, and the state was $\{P,Q,Y,Z\}$?  Observe that we by *square brackets* denote a *sequence* (i.e., an ordered list) and by *curly brackets*, an unordered set (the usual kind).

Action $E$ in state $\{P,Q,Y,Z\}$:  Precondition $Z$ is good since $Z$ is in the state.  Effect is "when $Q$, $\neg Z$".  The new state will thus be $\{P,Q,Y\}$.  We omit writing $\neg Z$ since every element *not* occurring in the state will be assumed to be not held.

Action $D$ in state $\{P,Q,Y\}$:  Precondition $\neg X$ is good.  Effect: "when $Q$, $X$".  Hence new state will be $\{P,Q,X,Y\}$.

Action $A$ in state $\{P,Q,X,Y\}$:  Precondition is good, $X$ is in the state.  Effect: "when $P$, $\neg X$, and $Z$".  $P$ is in the state, hence we remove $X$ and we also add $Z$.  New state is $\{P,Q,Y,Z\}$.

Action $B$ in state $\{P,Q,Y,Z\}$: Precondition $Y$ is good.  Effect "when $Z$, $\neg P$, also $\neg Y$, $\neg Z$ and $X$".  $Z$ is true, hence we lose $P$.  We also lose $Y$ and $Z$ and gain $X$.  New state is $\{Q,X\}$.

Action $C$ in state $\{Q,X\}$: Precondition is $\neg Z$, so good.  Effect: "when $P$, $\neg X$, and $Y$".  This is the first time we encounter an implication in which the antecedent $P$ is false, so we don't remove $X$.  We still add $Y$, though.  Hence the new, and final state is
$$
\{Q,X,Y\}.
$$

Comment: wow I didn't expect an answer this detailed. Thank you so much I now fully understand how the flow works now! Too bad I don't have enough rep to vote you up..

Comment: didn't know "Action(B, Precond:{Y}, Effect:{when Z : ~P), ~Y,~Z,X})" means if there is a Y in {P,Q,Y,Z} replace Z by deleting P,Y and put X in it so it becomes {Q,X}. I was thinking why on earth doesn't the EFFECT include all the states into a bracket like {(when Z:~P,~Y,~Z,X)}) confused me loads

Comment: There is a typo in your example, it should be:  Action(B, Precond:{Y}, Effect:{(when Z : ~P), ~Y,~Z,X}).  It means that if you want to do Action B, you need to have Y in your state.  Furthermore, after action B has been done, you do not have Y, nor Z, but you have X.  Furthermore, if Z was in the state before the action, then you will no longer have P.